# Caliburn and prism samples

Tags: sample, prism, caliburn

Are there any sample applications avaliable that make use of both caliburn and prism?

I know there are blogs that talk about it but I would like to wade into some code and see how it all fits together.

http://caliburn.codeplex.com

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that there are any public projects that use both together.  However, if you look in Caliburn's samples, you will find a basic sample configured to use Prism with Caliburn.  It's under the HowTos folder.